# Is every closed ball in metric space X bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Assume that we have a metric space $X$ with Euclidean metric, and $r$ is a positive real number. Now let $B(a, r) = \{x \in X : d(a, x) \leq r\}$. Is $B(a, r)$ bounded?

To me it seems that $0$ is a lower bound and $r$ is an upper bound, thus $B(a ,r)$ is bounded. Am I right? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I think you're confusing the definition of "bounded subset of a metric space" with "bounded subset of $\mathbb R$. The former is just a set contained in a ball of finite radius, and has nothing to do with upper and lower bounds (which don't make sense in a general metric space).

Comment: Yes. You are right, I don't know why I mixed it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A set in a metric space is bounded if it is contained by a ball of finite radius, in this case $B(a,r)$ itself does the trick. The ball bounds itself, look at the definition on wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set#Metric_space

Comment: Note that it's not necessarily _totally_ bounded, which means that for any given $r'$, the set can be covered by finitely many balls of radius $r'$.

Comment: Ah I see. So you mean since $B(a ,r)$ is contained in itself, and has a finite radius, then it is bounded?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$B(a,r)$ is a set, whose all elements have euclidean distance less than or equal to some positive number $r$ from a point $a \in X$. So it is bounded.